# difference between ftp -iv internet and ftp -ivn $server commands

Tags: unix, ftp

I am having the below shell script which tries to connect to the ftp server and puts a jar file in that ftp server from the linux application server

```
#ftp -iv internet << ! >> /home/abc.log
ftp -ivn $server << ! >>   /home/abc.log
user $2 p
binary
quit
```

I want to know what is the difference between ftp -iv internet and ftp -ivn $server?

Answer (score 0):

The `-n` switch of [`ftp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp) is for:

> Restrains `ftp` from attempting ''auto-login'' upon initial connection.

Without `-n`, `ftp` would prompt for username and password.

With `-n` this does not happen. Instead, your script explicitly logs in using the `user` command.

Comment: `ftp internet` connects to host "internet", while `ftp $server` connects to a host stored in a shell variable `server`.

Comment: thanks for the response. And please tell me what is the difference in using ftp internet and ftp $server as shown below.
ftp -iv internet << ! >> /home/abc.log
ftp -ivn  $server << ! >>   /home/abc.log
Here $server contains the server name. Since several years the script was using “internet” option for ftp and it was working fine. Suddenly it stopped working. And I just got it by googling that ftp with internet option is used for firewall connections. 
When I changed to ftp with $server, it started working.

Comment: I have nothing to add to what I already wrote in my previous comment. We do not know the value of your `server` variable. We do not know anything about your network nor your firewalls. Please, talk to your network administrator.